# Задача на JAVA. Дачники

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Добрый день! Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, где ошибка в задаче.

**Задача:**

> Всем известно, что дачники – народ странный, почти такой же, как и программисты. Строят они свои дачи непонятно где, да и выращивают там непонятно что и непонятно зачем. А уж как они туда добираются, это другая история: кто на автобусе, кто на электричке, кто на автомобиле, ну а кто-то вовсе пешком ходит от дома и до самого участка. Так что не стоит удивляться, если вдруг Вы узнаете, что некое садоводческое товарищество располагается на острове, а дачники добираются до него самолетом. Да еще и на этом острове может не быть посадочной полосы, так что высадиться на остров можно, только прыгая с парашютом (мы уж не рассматриваем то, как они возвращаются с дач домой). Рассмотрим этот уникальный случай. Пилот всегда старается осуществить высадку парашютистов таким образом, чтобы дачники приземлялись как можно ближе к своим прямоугольным участкам. Пилоту интересно знать: сколько дачников приземлится на свои участки? Помогите ему решить эту задачу!

**Входные данные:**

В первой строке входного файла `INPUT.TXT` записано натуральное число `N (1 ≤ N ≤ 1000)` – количество дачников, далее идут `N` строк, в каждой из которых описаны координаты каждого дачника и его участка:
`X, Y, X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3, X4, Y4` где `X, Y` – координаты приземления парашютиста `X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3, X4, Y4` – координаты прямоугольного участка на плоскости, указанные последовательно.
Все координаты – целые числа, не превышающие `50000` по абсолютной величине

**Выходные данные:**

В выходной файл `OUTPUT.TXT` нужно вывести количество дачников, приземлившихся на свой участок. Попадание на границу участка считается попаданием на участок.

Пример
[image: Входные данные]

Я решил соединить точку высадки дачника с вершинами прямоугольника и сложить площади получившихся четырёх треугольников. Далее вычислить просто площадь прямоугольника и если оная совпадает с суммой треугольников то дачник попал на свою площадь. На, в результате программа выводит номера всех дачников. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем дело.

**Вот программа:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.N;

public class T_12  {
    static int N;
    PrintWriter pw;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new T_12().run();
    }

    public void run() throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\sbeskhmelnitskiy\\Desktop\\input.txt"));
        pw = new PrintWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\sbeskhmelnitskiy\\Desktop\\output.txt"));
        N = sc.nextInt();
        //Создаю дачников и считываю их координаты
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            Human h = new Human();
            for (int t = 0; t < 5; t++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                    h.coord[t][j] = sc.nextInt();
                }
            }
            //Передаю Дачника и его номер(для его вывода в файл если он попал к себе), на проверку.
            check_human (h, i);
        }
        pw.close();

    }

    public void check_human(Human hum, int num) throws Exception {
        double areat = 0, areas = 0;
        //Считаю площадь четырех треугольников(соеденил точку приземления с вершинами)
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (i < 3) {
                areat += 0.5 * ((hum.coord[0][0] - hum.coord[i + 2][0]) * (hum.coord[i + 1][1] - hum.coord[i + 2][1]) - (hum.coord[i + 1][0] - hum.coord[i + 2][0]) * (hum.coord[0][1] - hum.coord[i + 2][1]));
            } else {
                areat += 0.5 * ((hum.coord[0][0] - hum.coord[1][0]) * (hum.coord[i + 1][1] - hum.coord[1][1]) - (hum.coord[i + 1][0] - hum.coord[1][0]) * (hum.coord[0][1] - hum.coord[1][1]));
            }
        }
        //Считаю площать прямоугольника(разбил его на два треугольника и посчитал их площадь)
        areas = 0.5 * ((hum.coord[1][0] - hum.coord[3][0]) * (hum.coord[2][1] - hum.coord[3][1]) - (hum.coord[2][0] - hum.coord[3][0]) * (hum.coord[1][1] - hum.coord[3][1]));
        areas += 0.5 * ((hum.coord[3][0] - hum.coord[1][0]) * (hum.coord[4][1] - hum.coord[1][1]) - (hum.coord[4][0] - hum.coord[1][0]) * (hum.coord[3][1] - hum.coord[1][1]));

        if (areas == areat)
        pw.println (num+1);
    }
}
public class Human {
    double [][] coord = new double [5][2];
}
```

На выходе получается "1 2 3", а должна только "2". `areas` и `areat` получаются одинаковыми, хотя кроме второго дачника должны быть разными. В чем проблема подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: `... получаются одинаковыми, хотя кроме второго дачника должны быть разными.` Какое именно значение получается не таким как Вы ожидали? Если определить конкретный неправильный результат, то вопрос получится сократить до вида `почему эта строка дает результат X, хотя должна Y`. На такой вопрос Вам ответят быстрее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы считаете площадь, используя косое произведение, которое может быть отрицательным. Площадь же должна быть неотрицательной, то есть проще всего брать модуль. Другие улучшения: считать двойную площадь и тогда использовать целый тип (максимальное значение по условию: 2*(10^5)^2, вроде влезает), считать площадь прямоугольника как одно косое произведение.

Comment: Спасибо. А можно поподробнее, а то не совсем понятно. Где использовать модуль? Числа то все равно одинаковые.

Comment: @miltan13 Использовать модуль, когда вы вычисляете площадь. Например, так: `areat += Math.abs(0.5* ((hum.coord[0][0] - hum.coord[i + 2][0]) ... );`

Comment: Поставил везде модуль. Результат: 1)12.0-12.0 2)24.0-18.0
3)8.0-8.0. Пишет что одинаковые первый и третий, хотя должен быть только второй(

Comment: @miltan13 Там не второй должен быть одинаковым, а число попавших на участок — 2.

Comment: Извиняюсь @pocketgulag , вы были правы. Это в задаче не правильные результаты были. Огромное спасибо!!!!))

Comment: @miltan13, для этого есть кнопка принять ответ.